# get multiline data in parantheses without regex

Tags: python, brackets

I am trying to parse go metafiles in the format of following:

```
require (
    github.com/cheggaaa/pb v1.0.28
    github.com/coreos/go-semver v0.2.0 // indirect
    github.com/coreos/go-systemd v0.0.0-20190321100706-95778dfbb74e // indirect
    github.com/dustin/go-humanize v1.0.0
    github.com/fatih/color v1.7.0
        ...
        )
```

how do I get data between brackets and *without* using a regexp? (otherwise this noobish question would not exist at all). I have tried playing with `split()` but failed so far.

Comment: Maybe `[l.strip() for l in file.readlines()[1:-1]]`? Assumes it's formatted just like your example

Comment: What you expect to get?

Comment: Are there other lines in the file? Or is just that?

Comment: Why not use regex?

Comment: Can't understand what are you trying? Could you explain i/o?

Comment: @PeterWood because it would be overkill? (see - besides others - your own answer... :)

Comment: @SpghttCd a simple regex could catch more errors, and explicitly encode assumptions about the format that my code doesn't communicate.

Answer (score 1):

@rdas's suggestion of `[l.strip() for l in file.readlines()[1:-1]]` will work if the metafile is formatted like your example is. But really, you should just use regex. It's easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the entire contents, split it into separate lines, then slice off the first and last lines:

```
with open(metafile) as f:
    requirements = f.read().splitlines()[1:-1]
```

Using `with` to open a file ensures it is closed properly when the scope ends.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code that should do it. It will copy all the lines between 'requiere (' and ')' as long as there are no other ')' in those blocks.

data file:

```
random stuff
require (
    github.com/cheggaaa/pb v1.0.28
    github.com/coreos/go-semver v0.2.0 // indirect
    github.com/coreos/go-systemd v0.0.0-20190321100706-95778dfbb74e //indirect
    github.com/dustin/go-humanize v1.0.0
    github.com/fatih/color v1.7.0
        ...
        )



random stuff
```

out file :

```
github.com/cheggaaa/pb v1.0.28
github.com/coreos/go-semver v0.2.0 // indirect
github.com/coreos/go-systemd v0.0.0-20190321100706-95778dfbb74e //indirect
github.com/dustin/go-humanize v1.0.0
github.com/fatih/color v1.7.0
    ...
```

code :

```
f = open('data', 'r')
f2 = open('out', 'w')

toggle = False

for line in f:
    if 'require (' in line:
        toggle = True
        continue
    if toggle:
        if ')' in line:
            toggle = False
        else:
            f2.write(line)

f.close()
f2.close()
```